# Padding a number in a filename to a fixed length

Tags: shell, rename

I have a directory of files such as:

```
file.1.png
file.2.png
…
file.10.png
…
file.1000.png
file.1001.png
…
```

How can I pad the number to 4 digits? It should end up like this:

```
file.0001.png
file.0002.png
…
file.0010.png
…
file.1000.png
file.1001.png
…
```

Answer (score 6):

This will also work:

```
for f in *.png; do
    int=`basename $f .png | cut -d '.' -f 2`
    new_name=`printf "file.%0.4i.png\n" $int`
    [ ! -f $new_name ] && mv $f $new_name
done
```

Comment: +1 since this handle the not asked for file.11001.png as well as fixing the described examples.

Answer (score 5):

A simple trick if you want a simple, portable script is to start counting at 10001 and strip the initial digit.

```
for x in file.*.png; do
  n=${x%.*}; n=${n##*.}
  n=$((n + 10000))
  mv "$x" "${x%.*.*}.${n#1}.${x##*.}"
done
```

With zsh, using [zmv](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) and the [`l` parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

```
setopt extended_glob
autoload zmv
zmv '(file).([0-9]##).(png)' '$1.${(l:4::0:)2}.$3'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
for f in *.png
do
   foo='0000'${f#file.} #remove "file." and prepend 0000
   foo=${foo:(-8)} #last eight characters
   echo mv $f file.$foo   
done
```

Remove the echo if you are happy with the output.

Comment: -1 If you have 5 or more digits like file.11001.png, then that file will become file.1001.png since all filename gets 4 digits with this solution. frogstarr78:s example with printf is a better.

Comment: @Johan the question asks "How can I pad the number to 4 digits?" That's what I answered. It's not supposed to work for 5 or more digits.

Comment: Your answer does kind of answer the question, but in the question is also a couple of ... after file.1001.png that implies that there could be higher numbers. If you had a note about this limit then I would not have downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the `rename` command from the Perl package (as opposed to the one from the util-linux package):

```
rename 's/(\d+)/sprintf"%04d",$1/ge' file.*.png
```

Alternative based on glenn jackman' comment, which suggests a portable solution involving Perl. As Perl has its own `rename` function, there is no more need for the external `mv`:

```
ls -1 file.*.png | perl -ne 'chomp;($n=$_)=~s/(\d+)/sprintf"%04d",$1/ge;rename$_,$n'
```

That code is easier to enhance to reproduce the extras added by the `rename` external command: skip if the new file name is identical with the old one and skip if there is already a file with the new name:

```
ls -1 | perl -ne 'chomp;($n=$_)=~s/(\d+)/sprintf"%04d",$1/ge;rename$_,$n if$_ ne$n&&!-f$n'
```

With some adaptation, a loop-less solution can be achieved even with Sed:

```
ls -1 file.*.png | sed -r '/[0-9]{4}/d;h;:p;/[0-9]{4}/!s/([0-9]{1,3})/0\1/;tp;G;s/(.+)\n(.+)/mv \2 \1/' | sh
```

Comment: and if you don't have rename, `mv "$f" "$(perl -pe 's/(\d+)/sprintf"%04d",$1/ge' <<< "$f")"` (assuming you use bash)

Comment: @glennjackman Yes, in this case probably will do the job. But will give error messages for all files where the number already has 4 digits and will overwrite existing files.

Answer (score 2):

There are already quite a few answers here, but I thought I'd throw up a simple one

```
rename 'file.' 'file.000' file.?.png
rename 'file.' 'file.00' file.??.png
rename 'file.' 'file.0' file.???.png
```

The `rename` utility comes standard on every distro I know of. Its not as fancy as some of the other solutions here, but simple is easy to remember.

The first line takes `file.1.png` and converts it to `file.0001.png`.
The second converts `file.10.png` to `file.0010.png`, and the third does `file.100.png` to file.0100.png.
The 4 digit ones are already done.

Comment: It's not on Mac OS X, at least not by default.

Comment: @EdwardFalk - it's part of `util-linux` so no, it's not on Mac OS X.