# How to rename to fixed length

Tags: shell-script, rename

I have files named as `0-n.jpg` for `n` from 1 to 500, for example.

The problem is that some guy using Windows didn't use leading zeros so when I do `ls` I obtain

```
0-100.jpg
0-101.jpg
...
0-10.jpg
...
0-199.jpg
0-19.jpg
0-1.jpg
```

So I'd like to rename them to insert the leading zeros, so that the result of `ls` could be

```
0-001.jpg
0-002.jpg
...
0-100.jpg
...
0-499.jpg
0-500.jpg
```

In other words, I'd like all files with the same file name lengths.

I tried [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/21440/19195) but I'm getting a sequence of errors like

```
bash: printf: 0-99: invalid number
```

Comment: Well, your situation is a bit different from the one you linked to. The general approach will work, but your numbers are not separated by `.`, but by `-` and `.`, which will require some modifications to the script. How did you modify the script?

Comment: I'm testing it before using only `echo` to see the output. `for f in *.jpg; do int=`basename $f .jpg | cut -d '.' -f 2`; echo $int; new_name=`printf "e.%04i.jpg\n" $int`; echo $new_name; done;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your system has the perl-based `rename` command you could do something like

```
rename -- 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/sprintf("%d-%03d",$1,$2)/e' *.jpg
```

Testing it using the `-v` (verbose) and `-n` (no-op) options:

```
$ rename -vn -- 's/(\d+)-(\d+)/sprintf("%d-%03d",$1,$2)/e' *.jpg
0-10.jpg renamed as 0-010.jpg
0-19.jpg renamed as 0-019.jpg
0-1.jpg renamed as 0-001.jpg
```

Comment: Ow, perfect! It worked. So to rename the files I only need to remove the `-vn` options?

Comment: @Sigur, you only need to remove the `-n` option, which means "don't actually rename anything".  The `-v` option prints the message about each file renamed, which you can keep or remove as you like.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `zsh` shell, you could do something like below.

```
zmv '([0-9])-([0-9]##).(jpg)' '$1-${(l:3::0:)2}.$3'
```

**Testing**

```
touch 0-1.jpg
touch 0-23.jpg
touch 0-345.jpg
touch 0-6.jpg
touch 0-05.jpg
```

Change the shell to `zsh` and if `zmv` is not loaded, you could do `autoload zmv`.

Now, you could add `-n` flag to the `zmv` command to see what will happen if you execute the `zmv` command. I am running the command as,

```
zmv -n '([0-9])-([0-9]##).(jpg)' '$1-${(l:3::0:)2}.$3'
```

The output is,

```
zmv -n '([0-9])-([0-9]##).(jpg)' '$1-${(l:3::0:)2}.$3'
mv -- 0-05.jpg 0-005.jpg
mv -- 0-1.jpg 0-001.jpg
mv -- 0-23.jpg 0-023.jpg
mv -- 0-6.jpg 0-006.jpg
```

If you are satisfied the file names are renamed correctly, you could remove the `-n` flag.

**References**

Thanks to user Gnouc for clarifying my doubt on this question which I had posted as another question to get this solution and the link to Gnouc's answer is [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/155794/47538) one.

Answer (score 2):

another solution in case you do not have "rename:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
   [ -f "$file" ] || continue  #skips if no jpg file present in current dir
   echo "${file}" | awk -F'[-.]' '
      {   new=sprintf("%03d",$2); 
          print "echo TESTING mv ", $0," ",$1"-"new"."$3 
      }'
done | bash
```

(edit: moved the `| bash` so it's only invoked once, and not once per file. And this quick loop is not "weird filename" friendly, but could be sanitized further (to handle files with spaces, etc))

and remove the 2 words `echo TESTING` to really do the `mv ...`, once you are sure it's doing what you want it to do.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to follow your code. I didn't know about `sprintf`.

Comment: Sprintf is a printf that also outputs its result as a string (= string printf), so it can be assigned to a variable

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach. Since you only need to rename a specific subset of files and since you already know what those are, just list them and rename them:

```
for i in {1..99}; do mv -- 0-$i.jpg 0-$(printf '%03d\n' $i).jpg; done
```

That will list the numbers from 1 to 99, saving each value as `$i`. You don't care about the rest since those are already named correctly. You then rename `0-$i.jpg` to the padded version. The `printf` `%03d` directive will print a number adding 0s to the left hand side if it is less than 3 characters in length. The result is that all your problematic files will be renamed.

Comment: What is the meaning of `--` after `mv`?

Comment: @Sigur it's there to tell `mv` that there are no more command line flags to process. It is useful when you need to pass a file name that contains a `-` and could be interpreted as an option.

Comment: @Sigur `--` tells the command that the arguments that follow it aren't options, even if they start with `-`. It isn't actually necessary here since the remaining arguments all start with `0`, but it's a good habit to follow.

Comment: A better habit to follow would be to add ./ to each filenames (as it works with every commands, even those who don't have '--', even maybe some old rm somewhere?) (But of course my answer needs this plus many other things to handle weird cases gracefully too)