# zmv command to rename file after matching pattern

Tags: zsh, rename

I was trying to figure out a solution for [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155775/how-to-rename-to-fixed-length) question using `zmv`. I am unable to find an exact solution using `zmv`. This is what I could come up with so far.

From [here](http://grml.org/zsh/zsh-lovers.html), I could rename all files like `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, `34.jpg` etc as `001.jpg`, `002.jpg` and `034.jpg` using the command,

```
zmv '(<1->).jpg' '${(l:3::0:)1}.jpg'
```

Now, I need to modify `zmv` to have some patterns in the beginning so that I can rename the files. However, I am not able to accomplish this. The closest I could find is this [solution](http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv).

```
c=1 base='0-' zmv '*.jpg' '${base}${(l:3::0:)$((c++))}.jpg'
```

However, the problem with the above approach is if I have files as `0-1.jpg`, `0-44.jpg`, the above command will replace it as `0-001.jpg` and `0-002.jpg` instead of `0-001.jpg` and `0-044.jpg`.

How should I modify the `zmv` command to accomplish the renaming as desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [-l expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags):

> l:expr::string1::string2:
>
> Pad the resulting words on the left. Each
>   word will be truncated if required and placed in a field expr
>   characters wide.
>
> The arguments :string1: and :string2: are optional; neither, the
>   first, or both may be given. Note that the same pairs of delimiters
>   must be used for each of the three arguments. The space to the left
>   will be filled with string1 (concatenated as often as needed) or
>   spaces if string1 is not given. If both string1 and string2 are given,
>   string2 is inserted once directly to the left of each word, truncated
>   if necessary, before string1 is used to produce any remaining padding.
>
> If the MULTIBYTE option is in effect, the flag m may also be given, in
>   which case widths will be used for the calculation of padding;
>   otherwise individual multibyte characters are treated as occupying one
>   unit of width.
>
> If the MULTIBYTE option is not in effect, each byte in the string is
>   treated as occupying one unit of width.
>
> Control characters are always assumed to be one unit wide; this allows
>   the mechanism to be used for generating repetitions of control
>   characters.

Try:

```
zmv '([0-9])-([0-9]##).(jpg)' '$1-${(l:3::0:)2}.$3'
```

Answer (score 2):

Beware that `${(l:3::0:)var}` will pad with zeros but will also truncate a `var` that is more than 3 characters long (`1234` will be changed to `234`).

Another alternative is to use `typeset -Z3` à la `ksh`:

```
typeset -Z3 z3
zmv '([0-9]-)(<->)(.jpg)' '$1${${z3::=$2}+}$z3$3'
```

We're using `${${z3::=$2}+}` above to trigger the assignment to `z3`. The next `$z3` expands `z3` so with 0 padding.