# order for listing files

Tags: bash, filenames, wildcards, sort

If I have a list of files under a directory

```
ullman-000.pbm
ullman-001.pbm
...
ullman-098.pbm
ullman-099.pbm
ullman-1000.pbm
ullman-1001.pbm
ullman-1002.pbm
ullman-1003.pbm
ullman-1004.pbm
ullman-1005.pbm
ullman-1006.pbm
ullman-1007.pbm
ullman-1008.pbm
ullman-1009.pbm
ullman-100.pbm
ullman-1010.pbm
ullman-1011.pbm
ullman-1012.pbm
ullman-1013.pbm
ullman-1014.pbm
ullman-1015.pbm
ullman-1016.pbm
...
```

When using `ullman*.pbm` to refer to them and pass it to command `convert ullman*.pbm ullman.pdf` as input files, how can I make them in the order of

```
ullman-000.pbm
ullman-001.pbm
...
ullman-098.pbm
ullman-099.pbm
ullman-100.pbm
...
ullman-999.pbm
ullman-1000.pbm
ullman-1001.pbm
ullman-1002.pbm
ullman-1003.pbm
ullman-1004.pbm
ullman-1005.pbm
ullman-1006.pbm
ullman-1007.pbm
ullman-1008.pbm
ullman-1009.pbm
ullman-1010.pbm
ullman-1011.pbm
ullman-1012.pbm
ullman-1013.pbm
ullman-1014.pbm
ullman-1015.pbm
ullman-1016.pbm
...
```

Thanks?

Comment: Are you sure that's not the default behaviour ?

Comment: @sputnick The default behaviour is lexicographic. OP wants numeric.

Comment: If you can, try renaming all the files so that they have four digits (padded with zeros).

Comment: I don't have this problem with bash 4 http://pastie.org/9766149

Comment: @sputnick Your three digit numbers conveniently begin with 0.

Comment: @muru:Thanks. How can i rename all the files so that they have four digits (padded with zeros) with the files given?

Comment: You can do it with krename, if you want it easy. Or some contraption with sed, probably.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `sort` and `xargs` might do the trick

```
printf '%s\0' ullman*.pbm | sort -z -k2,2n -t'-' | xargs -0 convert
```

First check this works by listing files without calling `convert`

```
printf '%s\0' ullman*.pbm | sort -z -k2,2n -t'-' | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
ullman-000.pbm
ullman-001.pbm
ullman-098.pbm
ullman-099.pbm
ullman-100.pbm
ullman-1000.pbm
...
```

Whereas

```
printf '%s\0' ullman*.pbm  | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'                                                              
ullman-000.pbm
ullman-001.pbm
ullman-098.pbm
ullman-099.pbm
ullman-1000.pbm
..
..
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to rename the files that have three digit numbers to four digit ones, padded with a zero. If you have `perl-rename` (installed by default on Ubuntu) you can try:

```
rename -n 's/-(\d{3}\.)/-0$1/' *.pbm
```

Once you're satisfied with the result, run again without the `-n`.

Or see other options in [Padding a number in a filename to a fixed length](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21425/padding-a-number-in-a-filename-to-a-fixed-length).

Comment: Thanks, It also adds a 0 infront of those with 4 digits already. Damage has been done. How can I revert those files original with 4 digits?

Comment: @Tim i had a an error, forgot to to escape the `.`, which I corrected soon. Did you run it without the `-n`? If so, you can change the 3 to 4 and run the corrected version.