# Pad file names so Unix lists them in numerical order

Tags: bash, filenames, rename, macos

I have a folder with several files formatted as follows:

```
C Block Scan copy 1.pdf
C Block Scan copy 2.pdf
C Block Scan copy 3.pdf
C Block Scan copy 4.pdf
.
.
.
```

One issue I'm having is that when I run `ls`, Unix lists them as

```
C Block Scan copy 1.pdf
C Block Scan copy 10.pdf
C Block Scan copy 11.pdf
C Block Scan copy 12.pdf
.
.
.
```

I'd like to pad the numbers so that Unix (hopefully) lists them in order as

```
C Block Scan copy 01.pdf
C Block Scan copy 02.pdf
C Block Scan copy 03.pdf
.
.
.
C Block Scan copy 09.pdf
C Block Scan copy 10.pdf
C Block Scan copy 11.pdf
C Block Scan copy 12.pdf
.
.
.
```

I found a post with a similar problem, [Padding a number in a filename to a fixed length](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21425/padding-a-number-in-a-filename-to-a-fixed-length), but I tried applying their solution to my case and I couldn't get it to work. Here's what I tried:

```
for f in *.pdf; do
    int=`basename $f .pdf | cut -d '.' -f 2`
    new_name=`printf "file.%0.2i.pdf\n” $int`
    [ ! -f $new_name ] && mv $f $new_name
done
```

I admit that this is a blind adaptation of their solution to my situation, which I don't like because I don't really understand the underlying syntax, and I don't have a high enough rank on StackExchange to comment on that post yet.

I'm new to shell scripting, so an explanation of what the syntax means would be helpful and appreciated.

If it helps, I'm using the macOS Mojave 10.14.6, and I have Brew installed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't some new version of OSX convert to using zsh instead of bash? Are you convinced that bash is your shell and not zsh?

Comment: You did the right thing, by the way, by asking your own question. This gives you the benefit of explaining your exact situation. What error(s) do you get when trying other the answers on the other post? List the commands and the results by [editing your post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/573941/edit). Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller. I'm using bash. (`echo $SHELL` gives
`/usr/local/bin/bash`)

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, @JeffSchaller. I just updated my post.

Comment: You have `”` in your code which is not ASCII double quote but something else.

Comment: Are the names of files in the same format, always the same number of spaceS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find and rename all "*.pdf" files in the current directory whose names follow the
pattern described in the question to the same name but with number
padded to 2 digits:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in *[[:space:]][0-9].pdf; do
    int="$(basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev | cut -d . -f1)"
    name="$(basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev)"
    padded_int="$(printf "%02d\n" "$int")"

    echo mv "$f" "$(printf "%s %s.pdf" "$name" "$padded_int")"

done
```

Remove `echo` before `mv` to actually run `mv` but first run it as is
to make sure that it does what you want it to do. Example usage with
the above script saved to `pdf.sh`:

```
$ for i in {1..10}; do touch "C Block Scan copy $i.pdf"; done
$ ./pdf.sh
mv C Block Scan copy 1.pdf C Block Scan copy 01.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 2.pdf C Block Scan copy 02.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 3.pdf C Block Scan copy 03.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 4.pdf C Block Scan copy 04.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 5.pdf C Block Scan copy 05.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 6.pdf C Block Scan copy 06.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 7.pdf C Block Scan copy 07.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 8.pdf C Block Scan copy 08.pdf
mv C Block Scan copy 9.pdf C Block Scan copy 09.pdf
```

The first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).
Additionally, I use `env` for [its
features](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612980/why-is-usr-bin-env-bash-superior-to-bin-bash).

This line

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

sets *nullglob* [shell
option](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html)
which is also explained on the linked site:

```
nullglob

If set, Bash allows filename patterns which match no files to
expand to a null string, rather than themselves.
```

It's needed to prevent for loop from starting if there are no files
that match the pattern criteria:

```
for f in *[[:space:]][0-9].pdf; do
```

`*[[:space:]][0-9].pdf` is a shell pattern that means look for files
that have names composed of any number of characters followed by a
whitespace followed by a single digit and end with *.pdf*. Inside the
loop `$f` will hold a name of the processed .pdf file.

Here

```
int="$(basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev | cut -d . -f1)"
```

we use [command
substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)
to assign integer part of the given file name to a variable.  You can
see what `basename` does in `man basename` and reproduce the pipeline
in the terminal:

```
$ f='C Block Scan copy 1.pdf'
$ echo basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev | cut -d . -f1
1
$ f='C Block Scan copy 5.pdf'
$ echo basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev | cut -d . -f1
5
```

(Notice that `$` here is a [command line
prompt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface#Command_prompt)
used to indicate start of a new line, not a part of the command).

In the next line

```
name="$(basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev)"
```

we extract name part of the .pdf, that is everything before the
number.

In the next line

```
padded_int="$(printf "%02d\n" "$int")"
```

we use Bash built-in `printf` command to pad `$int` and save it to a
variable called `padded_int`.  In the last line in the loop

```
echo mv "$f" "$(printf "%s %s.pdf" "$name" "$padded_int")"
```

we run (without `echo` of course) the actual renaming using `printf`
and command substitution again.  `printf` is used with 2 `%s` format
specifiers and 2 corresponding arguments, similarly as in C.

The last line

```
done
```

closes the loop.

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! A couple of questions: 1) Any chance I could get an explanation of how the code works? I blindly copied and pasted it into a file like you said, but I'd like to understand what's going on. If you could recommend any good resources to learn it myself, that would be fine too. 2) You said to "Remove `echo` before `mv`", but I don't see `echo` anywhere here. Did I miss something?

Comment: 1. ok, I'll edit my post. 2. Umm, sorry, I forgot it, I've added it now.

Comment: @Data2Dollars: see edited answer

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I really appreciate it!

Comment: That's a great explanation. I have a few more questions, if that's OK: 1) `./pdf.sh` didn't work for me. I had to do `source pdf.sh`. Do you know why? 2) In `*[[:space:]][0-9].pdf`, how does precedence work? It seems like `*[[:space:]]` gets "greedily" matched before `[0-9].pdf` gets matched. Does "greedy" precedence work left to right? How does it work? 3) In `name="$(basename "$f" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f2- | rev)"`, why is there a dash before and after `f2` in `-f2-`? I see the difference in the outputs, but what does that syntax mean? Thanks again!

Comment: 1. no, I don't know why. You shouldn't have to source, just run it
`./pdf.sh`.  Do you get an error after running it instead of sourcing?
2. This is not an arithmetic expression, it's globbing. `*` matches
any string. Yes, it's greedy match. Yes, it works from left to
right. 3. read `man cut`: `N- from N'th byte, character or field, to
end of line`

Comment: 1. Oh, explain *doesn't work* and check if you have an executable bit set.

Comment: 1) Yes, it was a permissions issue. Once I did `chmod +x pdf.sh` to make it executable, `./pdf.sh` worked. 2) OK, got it. 3) I'll check that out. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh` (now the default user shell on macOS):

```
autoload zmv # best in ~/.zshrc
zmv '(* )([0-9].pdf)' '${1}0$2'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using P.E. parameter expansion. Only `mv` for external tools from the `bash` shell.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s nullglob

for f in *[[:space:]][0-9].pdf; do
  n=${f##* }  ##: Remain only 1.pdf, 2.pdf etc.
  n=0${n%.*}  ##: Remain only 1 , 2 etc. and pad 0 so it will be 01, 02 ..
  echo mv -v "$f" "${f/[0-9]/"$n"}"  ##: Replace all [0-9] with the value of "$n"
done
```

- See [Paremeter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)